# Apple program to view images on Windows OS

Tags: software-recommendation, windows

I recently updated iTunes on my windows 7 computer. Long time ago i set the default program to open image files on my commuter to an Apple program but after I updated iTunes that program is now gone or the settings have changed. I don't know the name of the program but it's an apple program that got changed after I updated iTunes. I've tried reinstalling Quicktime but that's not it.

I liked my old default image viewer because it was clean and simple and it did everything i wanted. Can anyone tell me the name of the program so I can choose that program as the default image opener?

Comment: From what I know Apple never released such app for Windows.

Comment: agree does not sound like any apple progrma that I know for Windows.   Are you talking of picture image file or disk image file?   Either way in windows: right click on file of that type. Choose Open With... then "CHoose Default Application"

Comment: Welcome to the site. You might want to ask on superuser.com how to use windows backup or other tools to determine the exact name of the software as we don't specialize in Windows OS knowledge, but I'll see if we can get any clue if it was QuickTime itself or perhaps some other product Apple connected / bundled with iTunes to view images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [windows system restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/system-restore) to go back in time and find the name of that pretty software, once you found it, restore to present and re-install/active it.

Comment: thank you. this solved my problem. It turns out the program was PictureViewer by Apple.